# Distinct left table rows on a left join

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I need to distinct the left table rows on a left join.

Instead of this

```
|  name  |  last name  |  phone  |
|--------|-------------|---------|
|  name1 |  lastname1  | 1234567 |
|--------|-------------|---------|
|  name1 |  lastname1  | 2345678 |
|--------|-------------|---------|
|  name2 |  lastname2  | 3456789 |
```

I need this

```
|  name  |  last name  |  phone  |
|--------|-------------|---------|
|  name1 |  lastname1  | 1234567 |
|        |             | 2345678 |
|--------|-------------|---------|
|  name2 |  lastname2  | 3456789 |
```

I tried with a SELECT DISTINCT but without success...
I tried also a GROUP BY but it hides the second row

Comment: use `group_concat` 
Try this SELECT name, lastname, GROUP_CONCAT(phone,' ') FROM table GROUP BY name

Comment: Added mysql tag as question title includes mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mariano, followed you here from your WP post that got closed.

```
<?php
$results = your_sql_query_here();
$data = array();

foreach( $results as $result ) {
    // Make a new array node for each name
    if ( ! isset( $data[$result['name']] )
        $data[$result['name']] = array();

    $data[$result['name']][] = $result['phone'];
}
```

This will give you something like this

```
Array(
    ['name1'] => Array(
        [0] => 5123451,
        [1] => 5123452
    ),
    ['name2'] => Array(
        [0] => 5123453,
        [1] => 5123454
    ) )
```

You can then just do a for loop of your `$data` array, using the key as your `name1` value.

Or store entire data sets

```
<?php
$results = your_sql_query_here();
$data = array();

foreach( $results as $result ) {
    // Make a new array node for each name
    if ( ! isset( $data[$result['name']] )
        $data[$result['name']] = array();

    $data[$result['name']][] = $result;
}
```

Now you will have access to all nodes, but grouped by `name`.

```
Array(
    ['name1'] => Array(
        [0] => Array( 'name' => 'name1', 'phone' => 4165123, 'another_field' => 1 ),
        [1] => Array( 'name' => 'name1', 'phone' => 4165157, 'another_field' => 0 ),
        [1] => Array( 'name' => 'name1', 'phone' => 4225157, 'another_field' => 0 )
    ),
    ['name2'] => Array(
        [0] => Array( 'name' => 'name2', 'phone' => 4165123, 'another_field' => 1 ),
        [1] => Array( 'name' => 'name2', 'phone' => 4572321, 'another_field' => 1 ),
        [1] => Array( 'name' => 'name2', 'phone' => 5235157, 'another_field' => 0 )
    ) )
```

Comment: hi Eric, thanks for following me. Problem is, will this system preserve the asoociations within fields? Because i have a lot more cols and the most of the fields can be left NULL...now, i should be able to preserve the phone numbers with the other fields on the same row and then print it. Alternative would be to abandon the left join method and use more then a query filtering by foreign key...

Comment: Well, you could always store the entire entry rather than specific fields. I'll throw in another example in the answer.

Comment: thanks, we're close to the point. I've corrected your code as i was receiving some errors and this is the var_dump: http://pastebin.com/B8GnDi9N as you can see i've grouped them by id instead of name. isn't it better to group only phone numbers? fer example something like this: http://pastebin.com/iuycEm56 . if not, i'm going to think on how to print only the non-repeating elements but if you have any suggestion, please advise. thanks a lot!! PS if you think it's better i'll open a new question

Answer (score 1):

You need [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

> This function returns a string result with the concatenated non-NULL values from a group.

So, your code will be:

```
  SELECT name, 
         last_name, 
         GROUP_CONCAT(phone) AS phones
    FROM table1
GROUP BY name, last_name;
```

Comment: nice solution but in the real situation i have a lot more cols...if i group all of them then i can't associate back the correct values while printing via php as some fields can be null...

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT()` but beware of that fact it has the limit on character length of 1024 default,but can can be increased

```
SELECT name, 
last_name, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT phone SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM table1 
GROUP BY name, last_name
```

### [See fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd972a/1)

Comment: thanks for the fiddle Khalid, unfortunately this is not good for me as i explained to Alexander...i lose fields association if i do this as i have some fields that can be null

Comment: @Mariano can you post the schema of your table in sqlfiddle with sample dataset and update your question with desired result set

Comment: Khalid, i should post the whole db scheme to give you the real situation, are you sure you need this?

Comment: @Mariano not whole db schema only the required table schema with sample dataset

Comment: Hi Khalid, i'm following Eric's solution at the moment. It's a solution PHP side. If you have any opinion about it i will be glad to hear it. Thanks.